# why do I have to click twice to a submit input using selenium

Tags: google-chrome, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

**ENV**

chrome 32 webdriver2.8

I am using selenium(java) to click a submit input. But I need to click twice to active the submit operation.

The input code:

```
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="id_submit" name="submit" class="btn-txt" value="OK">
```

**NOT WORK** selenium code:

```
if(submitButton.isEnabled()) {
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(submitButton).perform();
    submitButton.click(); // this sentence is executed.
}
```

**WORKS**

```
submitButton.click();
submitButton.click();
```

Well, the first click function seems to make the button get focus, and the second click function active submit operation. When I use moveToElement to focus the button first, the click not work either. I can ensure that the button is enabled. I want to use selenium to click button and I dont want to do click twice. What should I do? Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT**

**WORKS EITHER**

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('id_submit').focus();");
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('id_submit').click();");
```

**UPDATE**

Imagine that I want to input a string, say "abcdef123456". Then send_keys is executed. It looks like
[image] and submit button is enabled. After click the submit button at the first time. It looks like[image] and submit button get focus. After click the submit button at the second time, the form is submited and page is redirected. I am confusing about the first *click*.

Comment: take a look at the html... `disabled='disabled'`  You aren't able (and shouldn't) click something that is unable to be interacted with.

Comment: `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(submitButton).perform(); submitButton.click();` is executed. So it should be enabled.

Comment: Does *click twice* is a bug of selenium or a solution of selenium?

Comment: Doesn't work. org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'focus')

Answer (score 2):

have you tried with [Expected Conditions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) class,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("id_submit"))).click();
```

Comment: Well,         `JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('J_submit').focus();");
        jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('J_submit').click();");` works for me. I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

It can solved like:
driver.sendkeys("abc1234"); (input in text box)

//explicit wait
WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Button")));
or
w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf((WebElement) By.id("Button")));

driver.findElement(By.id("Button")).click();

Comment: I did wait for `elementToBeClickable` 30sec，which not work for me. It is visible. So it's no need to wait for `visibility`.